# ServiceStack Custom ErrorResponse DTO

Tags: servicestack

We are currently using ServiceStack as our core framework for service provisioning. 
Does anyone know if it's possible to wrap custom exceptions into custom `ErrorResponse` objects?

From SS wiki:

> "In addition to the above options, you can override the serialization of ad-hoc exceptions by implementing the IResponseStatusConvertible.ToResponseStatus() method and have it return your own populated ResponseStatus instance instead."

That seems to fit with my needs, but I cannot figure out where I can override this serialization.

Again, I've tried to use custom `httphandler` by registering them within the AppHost, but they are not invoked when exceptions occur.

I am certainly missing something, is there anyone who can guide me through this?

Answer (score 1):

Here is ServiceStack's [Error Handling wiki page](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Error-Handling).

What it's saying is that you can control how the **ResponseStatus** is serialized if your custom exceptions implement `IResponseStatusConvertible`. Here is the source code example of [ValidationException](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack.ServiceInterface/FluentValidation/ValidationException.cs) implementing it:

```
public class ValidationException : ArgumentException, IResponseStatusConvertible 
{
    public IEnumerable<ValidationFailure> Errors { get; private set; }

    public ValidationException(IEnumerable<ValidationFailure> errors) : base(BuildErrorMesage(errors)) {
        Errors = errors;
    }

    private static string BuildErrorMesage(IEnumerable<ValidationFailure> errors) {
        var arr = errors.Select(x => "\r\n -- " + x.ErrorMessage).ToArray();
        return "Validation failed: " + string.Join("", arr);
    }

    public ResponseStatus ToResponseStatus()
    {
        var errors = Errors.ConvertAll(x =>
            new ValidationErrorField(x.ErrorCode, x.PropertyName, x.ErrorMessage));

        var responseStatus = ResponseStatusUtils.CreateResponseStatus(typeof(ValidationException).Name, Message, errors);
        return responseStatus;
    }
}
```

But this only controls how ResponseStatus is serialized, not how the generic responses are created. Look at the description of `IAppHost.ServiceExceptionHandler` or use a custom service runner if you want to change the error response returned.

Comment: Hi Demis,we are using IAppHost.ExceptionHandler instead of IAppHost.ServiceExceptionHandler which is not triggered. The problem we have is that our error response is appended to the default one that ServiceStack produces. We'll take a look at the Service Runner as well. Thanks a lot

Comment: @MarcoSerina `IAppHost.ServiceExecptionHandler` is only fired for exceptions inside Services. For exceptions happening outside (e.g. filters, request binders, etc) you can use `IAppHost.ExceptionHandler`.